# Can we cover a closed interval with open sets?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This might be extremely obvious but a proof such as [this one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120301091556AAtALsk) show a *"cover"* of [0,2] to be:

> the collection of open sets: $\{ (\frac{1}{n},2) \mid n \text{ is a positive integer} \}$

This is nice and gives us an open cover but when does it include the point 1, or 2? Does it not need to include these points to cover [0,2]? Right now I am only seeing it cover (0,2) or am I seeing something wrong?

Basically I am trying to prove that the interval

> [a,b] $= \{x \mid a < x < b\}$ for $a,b,x$ all rationals

is not compact. So I would like to use the set:

> $\{(a, b-1/n) \mid n \text{ is positive}\}$

To create my open cover with no finite subset but it just doesn't include the endpoints.. unless it does which this proof seems to be indicating. Could you let me know

- If you can cover closed intervals like this
- Any suggestions on my intended problem would be appreciated.

Comment: That set wouldn't cover [0,2].  The points 1 and 2 aren't in the alleged cover.  Any closed interval in the reals is compact, so your attempt to prove it isn't will fail.

Comment: Okay, would it be fine for me to keep my idea but just union the set with something like {x | 3a/4 < x < 5a/4} and {y | 3b/4 < y < 5y/4} to get the end points in there?

Comment: The set of *rationals* in any non-degenerate interval is *not* compact.

Comment: @dfeuer: :-) You’ve had some sleep now.

Comment: A union (even an infinite union) of open sets is still an open set. Thus, no union of open intervals contained in a closed interval can ever cover the closed interval.

Answer (score 2):

No, the set described does not cover $M=[0,2]\cap\Bbb Q$. There are two ways to look at compactness of a subset $S$ of a topological space, which turn out to be equivalent (as you should prove to yourself): one is compactness of $S$ when considered under the subspace topology, and the other is the statement that any set of open sets in the space whose union includes $S$ *as a subset* (also called an open cover of $S$) has a finite subset whose union also includes $S$ as a subset. Thus you don't need to think about open sets that lie *in* $S$ but rather more broadly.

Consider the following open cover of $M$:
$$\mathcal A=\{(-1,\sqrt 2)\}\cup\{(\sqrt 2+1/x,3)\mid x\in \Bbb R_+\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

take an increasing sequence of irrational numbers $y_{k}$ such that $0< y_{k}< y<2$, for all $k$, where $y$ is an irrational number and the cover will be $(y_{k},y_{k+1})\cup[0,y_{1})\cup(y,2]$.